# How do I split words in Python while keeping in consideration words with hyphens?

Tags: python, regex

In Python, `re.split("\W+", "fat-free milk")` yields `['fat', 'free', 'milk']`.

How do I produce `['fat-free', 'milk']` from `re.split()`?

I understand the problem to be that hyphens are not alphanumeric characters, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this fact into the regex. I have tried `re.split("[(^\-)\W]+", "fat-free milk")` to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
re.split("[^-\w]+", "fat-free milk")
```

Answer (score 9):

No need for a regex:

```
>>> "fat-free milk".split()
['fat-free', 'milk']
```

If you want to split on any non-word character that is not a hyphen you can use a negated character group (like in John's) answer or a negative lookahead, which might be slightly more flexible:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?:(?!-)\W)+', "fat-free milk. with cream")
['fat-free', 'milk', 'with', 'cream']
```

Comment: One would assume that they're using a regex to be able to deal with punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>a="fat-free milk fat-full cream"
>>>b=a.split(' ')
>>>print(b)
['fat-free', 'milk', 'fat-full', 'cream']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this

`re.split(" ", "fat-free milk")`